# Rearrange elements in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have something like this:

```
<MotionCapture height="480" dialogueFile="none" width="640" fps="30" numFrames="55" depth="200.0">
  <MocapFrame index="0">
    <Skeleton id="0">
      <Joints>
        <torso x="0,09970227" z="2,13386" y="0,02048468" />
        <neck x="0,139027" z="2,11847" y="0,3753783" />
        <head x="0,1632785" z="2,102617" y="0,5890977" />
        <l_shoulder x="-0,02443917" z="2,124225" y="0,2805836" />
        <r_shoulder x="0,301287" z="2,170277" y="0,2579407" />
        <l_hip x="0,01964889" z="2,067304" y="-0,1138878" />
        <l_knee x="-0,05473036" z="1,961696" y="-0,4850187" />
        <l_foot x="-0,1081518" z="1,841429" y="-0,7449498" />
        <r_hip x="0,1662257" z="2,089662" y="-0,1240771" />
        <r_knee x="0,1636017" z="2,024291" y="-0,5009199" />
        <r_foot x="0,1338794" z="1,972047" y="-0,8106034" />
      </Joints>
    </Skeleton>
  </MocapFrame>
.
.
.
</MotionCapture>
```

How can I rearrange the children contained by `Joints` so `head` and `torso` change places?

I've been looking and I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: How do you want to rearrange them?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60e5d13c-5ac3-4f26-99e8-8a6c53352112/how-to-rearrange-elements-in-a-xml-node-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: do you want to replace `head` and `torso` elements?

Comment: yes 
i want head to first in the list

Comment: Are you generating the xml, or just receiving it as input to your program?

Comment: You always want head first? What if the person is upside-down? Would sorting by `Y` be good?

Comment: I´m generating it from kinect data. Thing is data is return in the order that the xml shows

Comment: @JuanCarlosAllendeMena  Order in xml is not important. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a 3dmax extension that reads xml with a certain format and translate it to skeleton movement
i though i should replicate it in order to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, using `LINQ to XML` and [`XElement.ReplaceWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) method:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");
var Joints = xmlDocument.Descendants("Joints");

foreach (var joint in Joints)
{
    var temp = joint.Element("torso");
    joint.Element("torso").ReplaceWith(joint.Element("head"));
    joint.Elements("head").Last().ReplaceWith(temp);
}    
xmlDocument.Save("path");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite the torso with head?

Comment: @JuanCarlosAllendeMena  [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: im getting this :System.InvalidOperationException

on this line: joint.Elements("head").Last().ReplaceWith(temp);

Comment: @JuanCarlosAllendeMena all `Joint` elements contains one `torso` and one `head` right ? then it shouldn't give you that error.I tried your  sample xml and it worked correctly